# Generate combinations of different sets

Tags: java, guava

I'm having 3 collections of the same Object but every object has a type property like an enum.

Every collection has Objects with the same type property. 
So set 1 all the Objects properties are different except for the type property, same for all the other sets.

Now I want to have all combinations with those 3 sets with respect that for example the result set needs to have 1 item of set1, 2 items of set2 and 1 item of set3 (this is configurable).

So what I tried was to merge those 3 sets into one set and use google guava Sets.combinations(bigSet, 4) to get all the combinations of those sets of size 4. Afterwards I would filter out the sets that don't satisfy those rules.

I'm worried that this is not the most efficient way to do this. Because first the method generates more combinations then I need and afterwards I need to filter 3 times (1 per set) to remove the sets that doesn't have the correct number of type objects. So if in the future I need an extra set it needs to filter 4 times.

Is there a better way to generate those sets?

Dummy class:

```
public class Dummy {
    String name;
    Type type;

    public Dummy(String name, Type type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dummy{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type=" + type +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
    Dummy d1 = new Dummy("Rik", Type.TYPE1);

    Dummy d2 = new Dummy("John", Type.TYPE2);
    Dummy d3 = new Dummy("Bart", Type.TYPE2);

    Dummy d4 = new Dummy("Elisabeth", Type.TYPE3);
    Dummy d5 = new Dummy("Annie", Type.TYPE3);

    Set<Dummy> dummySet1 = ImmutableSet.of(d1);
    Set<Dummy> dummySet2 = ImmutableSet.of(d2, d3);
    Set<Dummy> dummySet3 = ImmutableSet.of(d4, d5);;

    Set<Dummy> result = new HashSet<Dummy>();
    result.addAll(dummySet1);
    result.addAll(dummySet2);
    result.addAll(dummySet3);
    System.out.println(result);

    Set<Set<Dummy>> combinations = Sets.combinations(result, 4);

    Set<Set<Dummy>> endResult = new HashSet<>();
    for (Set<Dummy> set : combinations) {
        long type1Count = set.stream().filter(s -> s.type == Type.TYPE1).count();
        long type2Count = set.stream().filter(s -> s.type == Type.TYPE2).count();
        long type3Count = set.stream().filter(s -> s.type == Type.TYPE3).count();

        if (type1Count == 1 && type2Count == 2 && type3Count == 1) {
            endResult.add(set);
        }
    }

    for (Set<Dummy> set : endResult) {
        System.out.println(set);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code with sample input and sample output?

Comment: I added some example code.

Comment: Thanks. See @kutschkem answer - it's right to the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead, as it will not generate invalid combinations:

```
Sets.cartesianProduct(
   Sets.combinations(Set1, set1Count), 
   Sets.combinations(Set2, set2Count), 
   Sets.combinations(Set3, set3Count));
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.